# Whenever I am building the first model in Logistic regression there is an error

Tags: regression, logistic

Whenever I am building the first model in logistic regression, it is throwing the error shown below. My code is:

```
mo2 <- glm(train3$Medal ~ ., data = train3[, -15], family = "binomial")

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

That is what it is showing, please help me with it.

Comment: Hi Shobs, questions focused on coding and debugging are off-topic on CrossValidated (but on topic at Stack Overflow). Also, check out [formatting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to see how properly format the text of your questions.

Answer (score 6):

The error message indicates that you include in your model categorical variables (i.e., `factor`s in R) that only have one category/level. You could exclude those with the following code:

```
keep <- function (x) {
    if (is.factor(x) || is.character(x)) {
        length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) > 1
    } else TRUE
}

train3. <- train3[sapply(train3, keep)]
```

Then you will need to use `train3.` in the call to `glm()`, i.e.,

```
mo2 <- glm(Medal ~ ., data = train3., family = binomial())
```

I have not excluded the 15th column in `train3.` as you did in your original code; you will need to do it yourself.